# Multilingual WPF Application: not working with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a multilingual WPF application using Andre's answer from [here](http://%3CButton%20Margin=%2251,82,108,129%22%20Name=%22button1%22%20Content=%22%7BStaticResource%20All_Vehicles%7D%22/%3E). I'm binding text like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Create}"/>
```

and can switch from english to french at runtime - nice! However, this does not work with ItemsSource. For example, I have a ComboBox that should display all available languages:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllLanguages, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource LanguageId}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Set up like this, the combobox displays no text. If I set the textblock's text inside to `Text={LanguageId}`, I see the LanguageIds 'eng', 'fr' etc., so the binding works.

When using a converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LanguageId, Converter={StaticResource DynamicResourceConverter}"/>
```

languages are displayed as "English" and "French". When I switch the language, however, the converter is not called again and the language names are not updated - so that is no real workaround.

I'd be very thankful for a tip on the cause and how to fix this.

Comment: Invalid Link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain first why a few things are not working.

```
    ....
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource LanguageId}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    ....
```

This is a short hand for `Text="{DynamicResource ResourceKey='LanguageId'}"` which is a static string literal and does not involve any binding.

It would be great if the following was available, but unfortunetly is **NOT POSSIBLE** because the target for the binding is not a `DependancyProperty`.

```
    ....
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={Binding LanguageId}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    ....
```

You are close with your workaround.  My suggestion would be to try the following:-

```
    ....
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DynamicResourceConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="LanguageId"/>
                    <Binding Path="SomeOtherPropertyThatChangesWhenLanguageIsSwitched" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    ....
```

You will need to expand the `DynamicResourceConverter` to now implement also `IMultiValueConverter`.  In a `MultiBinding` scenario, if either bound expression changes then the converter is called again.  You would write the `Converter` such that it only operates on `values[0]` of the supplied object array as the second value is not needed and only provided a trigger for the converter to be called again.

```
    public class DynamicResourceConverter: IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        ....
        // original converter implementation for IValueConverter
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ....
        }

        // newly added converter implementation for IMultiValueConverter
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //call the original converter method with one value (assuming you've checked the array has at least one item!!
            return Convert(values[0], targetType, parameter, culture)
        }

        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your help!